# How to add code snippets in Google Form questions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I want to make a quiz for students regarding basic programming using Google Forms. The challenge is that I can not find any Add On how add code snippets to the questions, like it is here in Stack Overflow, pressing Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a screenshot of the code, so that you can also get syntax highlighting, and publish it along with your question. Otherwise, link your code to other code-hosting websites such as pastebin.

Comment: Definitely not. At the moment, there is no option to do such a thing, sadly. Another alternative would be to create a WebApp instead of a Form, where you could use code syntax highlighting libraries. However, this would take a considerably higher amount of time...

Comment: I hoped that there could be some Add On about this, surprised that there is none

Comment: Sad, still no such add-on after a full year.